# Embedded python in C++: importerror importing numpy.core.multiarray

Tags: python, c++, numpy

I am developing a C++ program in Visual studio 2017 that should call a python script. I can import numpy in the VS interactive python, but when importing numpy in the file that gets called from main.cpp i get the error

```
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.
```

I am using Python 3.6, numpy 1.12.0, and building main.cpp in x64-Debug mode. I'm also using Cmake to build.

I have searched a lot, but I cannot find a working solution.

Comment: Have you tried what the error says? Try re-installing numpy

Comment: it could be a relative path error. E.g. make sure that the module is within sys.path. Check using `import sys` and then `print(sys.path)`

Comment: @Adosi Yes. I have tried with multiple versions of numpy (the internet says that 1.12.0 or 1.12.1 may remove the error). I have also checked that there are not other versions of numpy anywhere. I have installed numpy using pip in VS.

Comment: @Roars sys.path contains valid paths. The only difference between sys.path in VS interactive python and from the python file is that in VS i have a path to a python36.zip whereas in the .py--file it's to a python36_d.zip file

Comment: try running the exe (created when building the solution) from the folder that contains the python

Comment: @Roars, that creates errors in the main.cpp files when it tries to search for other included files. I have in the folder where the .exe file is created copied in a file called python36_d.dll. All other imports work, just not numpy (and packages that depend on it).

Comment: When I navigate to the folder where python.exe is installed and run python python.exe I can import numpy. If I instead run python_d.exe and try to import numpy I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I changed to using the boost/python.hpp header file. Although I'm building my application in debug mode it doesn't used the debug version of python. The import of numpy is now working.